# What is the most elegant way to get a database name from a connection string in Powershell?

Tags: regex, string, powershell

Title says it all. I have a database connection string that looks like this:

```
data source=some.server.net;initial catalog=MY-DATABASE;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;user=myusername;password=secret
```

Now, I would like to get the database name (MY-DATABASE) out of this string. There are dozens of ways to do this, but what would be the most elegant way to do this? Of course I could split the string by semicolons, generate key-value pairs and filter for the initial catalog. I could also simply find "initial catalog" and remove everything before that and after the semicolon from the string. I don't really like these options.

The most beautiful option would probably be to somehow use a regular expression. Having a *nix background I would solve it like this in bash:

```
connstr="data source=some.server.net;initial catalog=MY-DATABASE;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;user=myusername;password=secret"
echo $connstr | sed -r 's/.*catalog=([^;]*).*/\1/'
```

I figured that the PowerShell equivalent to sed would be the -replace parameter but I could not figure out how to use it in this particular case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Powershell I would do it like this (using `-match`):

```
$connstr="data source=some.server.net;initial catalog=MY-DATABASE;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;user=myusername;password=secret"
if($connstr-match".*catalog=([^;]*).*"){$matches[1]}
```

Comment: That is neat, I did not know about the $matches variable. I was rather confused that -match itself only returns a boolean value. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

No discussion if regex is beautiful, but a powershell solution using [ConvertFrom-StringData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-7):

```
# With PS7 using -Delimiter (Untested, I have no PS7 here)
$cs ='data source=some.server.net;initial catalog=MY-DATABASE;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;user=myusername;password=secret'
(ConvertFrom-StringData $cs -delimiter ";")."initial catalog"

# Older Versions
$cs ='data source=some.server.net;initial catalog=MY-DATABASE;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;user=myusername;password=secret'
($cs.split(";") -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData)."initial catalog"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$connstr = "data source=some.server.net;initial catalog=MY-DATABASE;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;user=myusername;password=secret"
$catalog = [regex]::Match($connstr,"(?<=catalog\=).*?(?=\;)").Value

"[$catalog]" # debugging output (displayed in square bracket)
```

> ```
> [MY-DATABASE]
> ```

Here in the `"(?<=catalog\=).*?(?=\;)")` regex pattern:

- `(?<=catalog\=)` is positive lookbehind for `catalog=` string,
- `.*?` is what we search for (lazy),
- `(?=\;)` is positive lookahead for `;` (a semicolon).